# How can I delete a table from the database/ an Entity in Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, entity

I deleted in mySQL my table `fields`.
In my entity folder I deleted also my entity `fields.php`

Now in the terminal I want to create a new entity with the name `fields`.
So I type

```
php bin/console make:entity fields
```

But now I get the error message:

> Compile Error: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader::loadClass():
>   Failed opening required
>   '/Users/work/project/vendor/composer/../../src/Entity/Fields.php'
>   (include_   path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.6/share/php/pear')

I added now the file `fields.php` again.

Now the error is gone - But I just cannot find out how to delete the Entity via terminal. There must be a way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a cache problem. Your entity was cached and registered for auto-loading but now cannot be found anymore. So you just have to refresh the auto-loader - I assume you're using composer

```
composer dumpautoload
```

and then clear Symfony cache

```
php bin/console c:c
```